# Springboot test fail because of table not found from H2 database, but the table has been created

Tags: spring, h2

The problem that I can see is that the table is created with the name 'article' and the query is done with ARTICLE in capital letter. I tried to change the application.properties file to this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MySQL;NON_KEYWORDS=USER;IGNORECASE=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
```

but it doesn't help the problem.

Here is some output from the console that demonstrate the table has been created:

```
Hibernate: create table "article" ("id" bigint generated by default as identity, "content" clob, "language" integer, "last_edited" timestamp, "published" timestamp, "title" varchar(255), "image_id" bigint, "user_id" bigint not null, primary key ("id"))
```

and later this pops up:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ARTICLE" not found; SQL statement: select * from Article where language=? ORDER BY published desc
```

I tried to name the table in uppercase letter with

```
DATABASE_TO_LOWER=FALSE, DATABASE_TO_UPPER=TRUE;
```

and it didn't help either.

What could I try next?

Comment: This exception clearly indicates that your connection URL wasn't actually used and Hibernate ORM created an own auto-configured database for tests with some default settings, tests may have an own configuration and you need to change it instead.

Comment: I think you are right, but I wonder how you got that from the error I posted? I checked the log and it says: 2022-07-27 21:03:45.171  INFO 214855 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:74539862-65b5-4c6b-bbad-7b269753a488;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
, which isn't like you said the URL connection I configured. The test only have a application.properties file and a .sql file, do I need to look into configurating something else?

Comment: @Evgenij Ryazanov thanks for the head up I solved the problem by adding this configuration to my test file: @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE).

Comment: With `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` (required for MySQL compatibility mode) H2 converts unquoted `Article` to `"article"`, but you can see upper-case `"ARTICLE"` in exception.